# TypeError: Cannot read property 'myDate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I am trying to make one rather basic code to work but receive a browser error. `expressjs` logs shows an  error as well.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'myDate' of undefined
>       at getReportTable (XXX\dist\controllers\crm\uploadHealthTable.js:18:70)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (XXX\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (XXX\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { uploadHealthTableSchema } from "../../models/crm/uploadHealthTableModel";

const reportTable = mongoose.model("USER_UPLOAD", uploadHealthTableSchema);

export class UploadHealthTable {

private myDate = new Date() ;

    public getReportTable(req: Request, res: Response) {
    reportTable.find({companyId: "18", uploadTime: { $gte: this.myDate.setDate(this.myDate.getDate() - 5) } },
    "_id fileName status uploadTime", { sort: {uploadTime: -1} }, (err, report) => {
        if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(report);
    });
    }
}
```

Call to this function -

```
export class CRMRoutes {
    public uploadHealthTable: UploadHealthTable = new UploadHealthTable() ;

    public routes(app: any): void {

        app.route("/support/reporttable/1/all")
        .get(this.uploadHealthTable.getReportTable) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `getReportTable`?

Comment: I am using expressjs (MEAN stack) and in the routes.ts file, calling below line -         app.route("/support/reporttable/1/all")
        .get(this.uploadHealthTable.getReportTable) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert this function to an *arrow function*

```
public getReportTable = (req: Request, res: Response) => {}
```

**Explanation**:
Because you passed the function as an argument, the `this` value is still at the previous function context

Useful links:

- [Typescript documentation for functions#this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this)
- [Typescript arrow functions](https://mdbootstrap.com/education/angular/typescript-9-arrow-functions/)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Query is not returning anything although there is data but that is separate issue. I will further troubleshoot and post another question.